# Python code gives urllib2 Error no 2

Tags: python, urllib2

I have been trying to run my python script and scraping data off websites using urllib2.However, all of the python scripts that i have written give the same error.
I am working on a windows and linux dual boot. the same code works fine on windows 7 but gives the following error when working on ubuntu 12.10.
The code is very basic:

```
      import urllib2
      response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
      html=response.read()
```

Here is the error:

```
     File "resp.py", line 2, in <module>
     response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
     response = self._open(req, data)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
     '_open', req)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
     result = func(*args)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in http_open
     return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
     raise URLError(err)
     urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Can someone suggest how to solve this problem? I am not working with a proxy so that is ruled out as a possible reason.

Comment: It works fine with me... and what does `urllib2.__version__` give you?

Comment: Can you try `$ wget http://www.google.com`?

Comment: wget gives this: Resolving false"; (false";)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `false";'

Comment: The code works for me as well, also on 2.7. Sounds like a DNS issue, that it cannot resolve www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error message: "Name or service not known".

I think it's just because your computer can not connect to www.google.com (You can't even resolve ip address of www.google.com). Try to `ping www.google.com`.

Maybe you are blocked by some fire wall(GFW, for example)

Comment: I did try pinging google.com and it works. However when i run the code it gives the same error.

Comment: What happens if you replace "www.google.com" with the ip you get from the ping operation?

Comment: Apparently the problem was with the apt.conf file. It had the proxy set to false which then gave an error when urllib tried to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Occurred:

In my script also i got the same error as you have mentioned ,i was able to solve my issue by changing the dns server ip.
May be change your dns server ip ,in linux dns server path is /etc/resolve.conf